# Get Selected value from Model Choice Field before Submission - Django

Tags: django

Good Morning for all !

I´ve researched many time how to do but not got it. I need to retrieve the value off Model Choice Field before submit it to show a diferent Modal Forms to the user fill it. Next see my codes. I this case, the field is **status**

I wiil appreciate so much your assistence.

Thank you !

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

FISICA = 1
JURIDICA = 2

CLIENTE_STATUS = (
    ('', 'Tipo'),
    ('FISICA', 'Física'),
    ('JURIDICA', 'Jurídica'),
)


class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    idade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, choices=CLIENTE_STATUS)


Views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from exemplo.forms import ClienteForm
from exemplo.models import Cliente
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView, DeleteView


class ClienteList(ListView):
    model = Cliente
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()


class ClienteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Cliente
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('exemplo:list')


class ClienteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Cliente
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('exemplo:list')


class ClienteDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()


class ClienteDelete(DeleteView):
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('exemplo:list')


Forms.py


from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from exemplo.models import Cliente


class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'

Template

cliente_form.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Criar Cliente</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cadastro de Cliente</h1>
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-3" style="font-size: 13px">{{ form.nome }}</div>
    <div class="col-3" style="font-size: 13px">{{ form.idade }}</div>
    <div class="col-3" style="font-size: 13px">{{ form.status }}</div>

    <div class="col-3" style="font-size: 13px">{{ self.get_status_display }}</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" onclick="location.href = '{% url 'exemplo:list' %}'">


</form>


{% if cliente.get_status_display == 'Jurídica' %}
    {{ cliente_get_status_display }}

Please make a payment to confirm booking.
<div class="col-3" style="font-size: 13px">{{ self.get_status_display }}</div>
{% endif %}


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am certain this will solve your questions since you are building CRUD + L application using Django class based view.

However, do it this way (total refactor):

On your views.py in your app:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from exemplo.forms import ClienteForm
from exemplo.models import Cliente
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView, DeleteView


class ClienteList(ListView):
    template_name = "my_app/my_template.html" #put your template here
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()


class ClienteCreate(CreateView):
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
    template_name = 
 "my_app/my_template_create.html" #put your template here

     form_class = ClienteForm #your form class from forms.py here

    def get_success_url(self):

          return reverse("exemplo:list") # make sure that your reverse URI matched the one you output in your url_pattern and that of template.

class ClienteUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 
 "my_app/my_template_update.html"
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
    form_class = ClienteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('exemplo:list')


class ClienteDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
    template_name = 
 "my_app/my_template_detail.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("exemplo:list")


class ClienteDelete(DeleteView):
    queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('exemplo:list')
```

You can add your own context_object_name at your ListView if you want.

The above will sort what you are doing out.

Goodluck Dev!

Answer (score 0):

My friend thank you so much your answer, but notting happend.  After I choose an option notting is show bellow, for exemple:

You choose ....... option !!! Are you sure to submit ?

My urls:

```
from django.urls import path
```

from exemplo import views

app_name = 'exemplo'

```
urlpatterns = [`enter code here`
path('', views.ClienteList.as_view(), name='list'),
path('create/', views.ClienteCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
path('update/<int:pk>/', views.ClienteUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.ClienteDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.ClienteDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
```

]

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOtuc.png)

Once more thank you your help !

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do it this way:
For URL:

```py
path('<int:pk>/', views.ClienteDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('<int:pk>/update/', views.ClienteUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),

path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.ClienteDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
```

Please I would like to see the template where this error is coming from or the error message you are getting from Django.template.loader

Comment: Hello Friend, notting change. In fact I don´t receive any error message, just not display the option that I selected before submit. Look I just want that display the same Option I selected in dropdown before I click Salvar (submit).
Repeat the same option I selected. Template is above (cliente_form.html). Thak you so much !!